# How can I best combine "get categories" and "has user access"?

Tags: mysql, innodb, relational-theory

I was wondering if it's possible to create a query for the following problem. I only want to select categories from the (MySQL) database (if the user has access).

- A user has multiple roles;
- A category has multiple roles.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  email VARCHAR(127) NULL ,
  username VARCHAR(16) NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(64) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE roles_users (
  user_id INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  role_id INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE forum_categories (
  id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  name VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  description VARCHAR(70) NULL ,
  image VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  parent_id INT(4) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE forum_categories_roles (
  category_id INT(4) NOT NULL ,
  role_id INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (category_id, role_id) ,
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

*I removed the relations*

Example:

- User A has role_id A
- User B has role_id B
- User C has role_id A and C

---

- category A has role_id A
- category B has role_id B and  C
- category C has role_id C and B

---

- user A has access to category A
- user B has access to category B and C
- user C has access to category B and C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the user id upfront, say id 12, then your query is

```
SELECT u.name username,GROUP_CONCAT('[',fc.name,']') categories
FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=12) u
INNER JOIN roles_users            ru  ON u.id = ru.user_id
INNER JOIN forum_categories_roles fcr ON ru.rol_id = fcr.rol_id
INNER JOIN forum_categories       fc  ON fcr.category_id = fc.id
GROUP BY u.name;
```

If you want to see all the categories for every user, then here is that query:

```
SELECT u.name username,GROUP_CONCAT('[',fc.name,']') categories
FROM users u
INNER JOIN roles_users            ru  ON u.id = ru.user_id
INNER JOIN forum_categories_roles fcr ON ru.rol_id = fcr.rol_id
INNER JOIN forum_categories       fc  ON fcr.category_id = fc.id
GROUP BY u.name;
```

Both of these queries return a comma-separated list of categories

I would recommend you also add an additional unique index

```
CREATE TABLE forum_categories_roles (   
  category_id INT(4) NOT NULL ,   
  role_id INT(11) NOT NULL ,   
  PRIMARY KEY (category_id, role_id) ,   
  UNIQUE KEY (role_id,category_id)
ENGINE = InnoDB   
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for but you put me in the right direction. Thanks :)

Comment: Please specify exactly what kind out output are you looking for. I can try to adjust my queries accordingly.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for accepting. Nonetheless, please edit the show me an example of the kind of output you are looking for, along with any inputs you want the query to have.

Comment: Sometimes it's a lost cause. You asked, he's seen it in the dropdown if he's logged back in. Good work on giving him new direction and letting him sort it out.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/6b58d79f290353b4d59d
The first query is for users (i used 'user_id' 2) and the second one is for guests (the ones that don't have any roles)